# In JS, How to run a piece of code only when multiple map functions are complete?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have several map functions which prepare the data I need. Then I run one line of code using those data. Now the problem is, the last line is executed twice. Before the map functions and after the map functions are complete. I need to run it only after the maps are complete. Here's an example :

```
// Initial declaration of the array
let countryColumns = [
  {
    name : 'abc'
  }
];

// I modify the array in the map functions
committees.map((committee) => {
  countryColumns.push({
    name: 'cba'
  });
});

countries.map((country) => {
  countryColumns.push({
    name: 'foo'
  });
});

// Then I load the view using those data with this line of code. I need to run this at last
onData(null, {countryColumns});
```

How can I do this? I tried to use the `async` package and it didn't work. Still the function ran twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map()` is a synchronous function.  As such, calls to `committees.map()` and `countries.map()` run synchronously and in order and they complete before the lines of code after them are run.

So, there's nothing tricky about synchronous code.  It runs in order and finishes synchronously.

So, the code you show will do the following:

1. Initialize `countryColumns`.
2. Run `committees.map()` to add items to `countryColumns`.
3. Run `countries.map()` to add items to `countryColumns`.
4. Call onData(null, {countryColumns});

The code you show will only call `onData()` once.  If it is getting called more than once, then this whole block of code is likely contained inside of something that itself is getting called more than once.  To fix that, you'd have to look outside this code to how this code gets called.

Comment: `js` at OP does not actually change `committees`, only calls `.map()` on items without setting new value for `committee`; e.g., `committees = committess.map()`?

Comment: @guest271314 - Yes, the OP's code merely uses `.map()` as an iterator.  They could have used `.forEach()` just as well.  Nothing in this code changes `committees` or `countries`.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The problem is in the way that function works. It execute that line of code when initiating and after the data change. Just fixed it by adding a variable which will be set to true when the data is ready.